# I am having problems with one of my assets in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

This probably doesn't have any thing to do with code but I thought I would post it here to see of eany one could help.

Basically I have a gun model on my main camera it doesn't have eany code on it yet. But wen I go into the game and move the camera up or down the gun seems to warp and extend in the direction I am facing it's probably really easy to fix but i am new to game development so eany help would be greatly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1135036/rotated-childs-geometry-changed-when-attach-to-par.html) UnityAnswers post will answer your question, since unexpected scalling behaviour when rotating is usually caused by non-uniform scaled hierarchy.